# HQL Syntax Exception while trying to Ignore Case Sensitive with IN condition in Spring Boot

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, hql

while trying to avoid Case Sensitiveness of 3rd Param which is List of String(Cars)
by using (UPPER(t.cars) in UPPER(?3) Getting Hql Syntax exception

```
@Query("select t from Usert where UPPER(t.name) = UPPER(?1) and UPPER(t.age) = UPPER(?2) and (UPPER(t.cars) in UPPER(?3) )")
    List<User> findByNameAndAgeAndCars(String name, String age, List<String> cars);
```

first two param able to work with UPPER() but list of String In Condition is not work with Upper if any body knows the solution could you please let me know

Comment: I don't have a direct fix for this, but one option would be to upper the list/collection before you call the JPA repo method.

Comment: share the stack trace of the exception

Comment: UPPER can only be applied to columns of type 'String' where as you are trying to use it with collection, which will always fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do something like

```
for(int i=0; i<cars.size(); i++){
    cars.set(i, cars.get(i).toUpperCase());
}
```

then, change your query to something like

```
@Query("select t from Usert where UPPER(t.name) = UPPER(?1) and UPPER(t.age) = UPPER(?2) and (UPPER(t.cars) in (?3) )")
```